# How to implement AAD multitenant app in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to create a multi-tenant application in AAD, where any organization can log in.
I can get an authorization token using my credential of course it is our organization so it will work. what I'm trying to achieve is to acquire token using the username and password e.g:

u: test@company1.com p: test1
u: test@company2.com p: test2
u: test@company3.com p: test3 etc...

I get the following error: **AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID [APP ID] Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.**

I have already executed the grant admin consent from API permissions but still, I've got an error. what settings did I miss?

This is the way I initialize the IPublicClientAppliction:

```
        var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdMultipleOrgs)
            .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
            .Build();

        var scopes = new string[]
        {
            "offline_access",
            "email",
            "https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All"
        };

        var authToken = app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes,email, 
                        password).ExecuteAsync();
```

Kind regards.

Comment: account from `@company1.com`  and `@company2.com` ... then did it work for one of the domain? I mean did it worked well when you used the account which domain is the same with the aad app you created from?

Comment: Hello, Yes it works on the same domain where I created the aad app.

Comment: Your application has to be registered in the customer tenant and the administrator has to give its consent to the application. Afterwards the application can be used by users of the customer tenant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent

Comment: I was thinking the same way but we do not want to bother all of our customers. what appropriate flow should I use then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below***:

I created an **Azure AD Multi-Tenant Application** like below:

[image]

I tried to generate the access token via **ROPC flow in Postman** by using the credentials of the same tenant user by using parameters like below:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/token

client_id : xxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
grant_type : password
scope : scope
username : user@********.onmicrosoft.com
password : ******
```

[image]

Please **note** that, ROPC flow supports only Local accounts (*Azure AD user accounts originally created in AAD tenant where application is created*). It doesn't support other tenant users/guest users.

***When I tried to generate the token by using credentials of other tenant user, I got the same error as below:***

[image]

**Reference:**

[Sign in with resource owner password credentials grant - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)

Comment: Thank you for your response. then what flow should I use then?

Comment: Is your requirement acquiring token using the username and password only?

Comment: No, We can use another flow. I use the username and password because I think it is the easiest and we're doing it to access email before the oauth2. Would you suggest another suitable flow that I can use? aside from username and password that can apply for multi-tenant?

Comment: You can make use of authorization-code flow/Client-Credentials flow to generate access token.

Comment: Do you have an example with those flows using C#? I was looking as well to generate access tokens silently. AcquireTokenInteractive shows a dialog to log in the credentials while the AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword didn't.

Comment: Please try to make use of Client-Credentials by referring to this MsDoc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#second-case-access-token-request-with-a-certificate

Comment: Hello, I don't understand how the client-credential works. I generate tokens with no user using AcquireTokenForClient. But I need the user to access the email. I'm using a mail kit.